# Суть просторечия

Tags: лексика

Чем отличаются понятия "Просторечие" и "разговорное выражение"?

Что вообще собой представляет просторечие? Это же в какой-то степени нормированное слово, почему же его не принято считать литературным? К "просторечиям" применимо понятие "Литературная норма"?

Comment: Здесь есть подробная информация: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/45969

Answer (score -1):

Как бы мягко написать, чтобы... не получится. Дело в том, что не всё в русском языке освещено на 100%, ещё много непонимания, и это непонимание никак не хотят развеять. Ведь попадут под давление и усмешки именитые деятели, которые окажутся безграмотными. Всё это не желательно. 
Придумана отговорка в виде: просторечное, разговорное, литературное. Как объяснить непонимание в толковании? Как? Как? Ответ: простым отсылом, мол: да это разговорное, просторечное... 
И таким образом непонимание остаётся. 
Пример с "нет" и "нету", где "нету" - разговорное!!! Пример с "ежели", "кабы", "коли"... Пример с глаголанием; пример с "извиняюсь"; пример с "утварь"; пример с "ратай" и "рать"; пример с "шелом" и т.п. Да, кстати, ещё есть оправдание типа - это же устаревшее. Непонимание легко объяснить, дав заключение типа: "просторечие", "устаревшее", "разговорное". Но почему устаревшее поныне в ходу?
Исправления, изменения, уточнения, на самом деле никому не нужны. Люди приучены к огрызку от русского языка и не принимают точности, чёткости, не могут узреть могущества русского языка - на сколько наш язык крепок и не поддаётся изменениям.